# Customizing Chart.js troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Have some trouble with Chart.js

1) is it possible to move bottom labels on top of the chart?
2) is it possible to hide left labels with first grey line?
3) is it possible to set up permanent tooltips(to show temperature) on every point instead of hover tooltips?

Here is my chart http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/ojc09hv4/:

```
<canvas id="weeksChart" width="651" height="335"></canvas>


var dayTemperatureArray = [-5, 14, 15, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 25, 24, 20, 19, 16];
var nightTemperatureArray = [-10, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 15, 17, 15, 13, 12, 11, 9];

var dataWeeks = {
    labels: ["16.02", "17.02", "18.02", "19.02", "20.02", "21.02", "22.02", "23.02", "24.02", "25.02", "26.02", "27.02", "28.02", "01.03"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Days temperature chart",
            fillColor: "transparent",
            strokeColor: "rgba(244, 6, 6, 1)",
            data: dayTemperatureArray
        },
        {
            label: "Nights temperature chart",
            strokeColor: "#3f6bf5",
            data: nightTemperatureArray
        }
    ]
    };

var ctx = document.getElementById("weeksChart").getContext("2d");
window.weeksChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(dataWeeks, {
    responsive: true,
    pointDot: true,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 0.5,
    scaleSteps: 2,
    scaleLabel: "<%=value + '°'%>",
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",
    showTooltips: true

});
```

Thanx a lot in advance!

p.s. please avoid jquery, if it's possible :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with the easiest one first

**2) is it possible to hide left labels with first grey line?**

I assume you meant the y axis labels. You can set the `scaleShowLabels` option to false in the chart options to hide the y axis labels

```
window.weeksChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(dataWeeks, {
    scaleShowLabels: false,
    ...
```

---

**1) is it possible to move bottom labels on top of the chart?**

I assume you mean the x axis labels. Chart.js doesn't have a direct option to do this. However you can hide the actual x axis labels and draw the x axis labels at the top of the chart by yourself.

Again, Chart.js doesn't have an option to hide x axis labels, but luckily there is an option to control the scale font color. Just set it to transparent and your original x axis labels are now hidden!

```
window.weeksChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(dataWeeks, {
    scaleFontColor: "transparent",
    ...
```

Now the drawing of the x axis labels at the top of the chart. To save us the trouble of extending the chart, we can add a post animation event handler and do this in that, like so

```
window.weeksChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(dataWeeks, {
     onAnimationComplete: function () {
          animationComplete.apply(this)
     }
     ...
```

with

```
var animationComplete = function () {
    var self = this;

    Chart.helpers.each(self.datasets[0].points, function (point, index) {
        self.chart.ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(self.fontSize, self.fontStyle, self.fontFamily)
        self.chart.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        self.chart.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        self.chart.ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
        self.chart.ctx.fillText(point.label, point.x, self.scale.startPoint);
    });
};
```

We just loop through all points in one of the dataset and add the labels (scale.startPoint is the top edge of the chart area)

*Note - why do we set the font, alignment, etc. every iteration? That's for when we add the tooltips.*

---

**3) is it possible to set up permanent tooltips(to show temperature) on every point instead of hover tooltips?**

The first step would be to actually show the tooltips. This is fairly simple, though a bit tedious. We loop through all the x axis point, build the label (by going through each dataset) and then construct a tooltip (fortunately, we can use Chart.MultiTooltip function for this.

We add it into the same loop we used to construct the new x axis labels. Since we need to color our tooltips, we need to get and store the set of colors in an array (which we pass on to the MultiTooltip function - we need to do this only once, so we take it out of the loop.

The modified animationComplete function is now this

```
var animationComplete = function () {
    var self = this;

    var tooltipColors = []
    Chart.helpers.each(self.datasets, function (dataset) {
        tooltipColors.push({
            fill: dataset.strokeColor,
            stroke: dataset.strokeColor
        })
    });

    Chart.helpers.each(self.datasets[0].points, function (point, index) {
        var labels = []
        var total = 0;
        Chart.helpers.each(self.datasets, function (dataset) {
            labels.push(dataset.points[index].value)
            total += Number(dataset.points[index].y);
        });

        new Chart.MultiTooltip({
            x: point.x,
            y: total / 2,
            xPadding: self.options.tooltipXPadding,
            yPadding: self.options.tooltipYPadding,
            xOffset: self.options.tooltipXOffset,
            fillColor: self.options.tooltipFillColor,
            textColor: self.options.tooltipFontColor,
            fontFamily: self.options.tooltipFontFamily,
            fontStyle: self.options.tooltipFontStyle,
            fontSize: self.options.tooltipFontSize,
            titleTextColor: self.options.tooltipTitleFontColor,
            titleFontFamily: self.options.tooltipTitleFontFamily,
            titleFontStyle: self.options.tooltipTitleFontStyle,
            titleFontSize: self.options.tooltipTitleFontSize,
            cornerRadius: self.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
            labels: labels,
            legendColors: tooltipColors,
            legendColorBackground: self.options.multiTooltipKeyBackground,
            title: point.label,
            chart: self.chart,
            ctx: self.chart.ctx,
            custom: self.options.customTooltips
        }).draw()

        self.chart.ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(self.fontSize, self.fontStyle, self.fontFamily)
        self.chart.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        self.chart.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        self.chart.ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
        self.chart.ctx.fillText(point.label, point.x, self.scale.startPoint);
    });
};
```

It looks complex, but all we are doing is passing a options that we copy from the chart instance options to the MultiTooltip function.

The tooltips all show up when the animation is complete. HOWEVER, once you move your mouse over the chart they all up and disappear! That's because the chart instance listens for multiple events to decide whether to start checking if tooltips should be shown - one of these is mousemove (and that causes it to redraw the chart, wiping out all our hard drawn tooltips and, if we are lucky, it draws a tooltip based on the point our mouse is hovering over)

This is a configurable option. So, all we have to do is remove all such events.

```
window.weeksChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(dataWeeks, {
    tooltipEvents: []
    ...
```

---

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fuodxsfv/

---

Unless your chart is wide enough, you will have tooltips (mostly the middle 2 ones) overlap (of course you could incorporate logic into the above loop to handle that), but anyhoo, those were actually meant to be tooltips!

Comment: Amazing!!! Thanx a lot!!!
Just one little clarification of the third part of my question:

Is it possible to set tooltip to each point separately from one each other? So, red line will have it's own tooltips on each point, and blue line will have it's own?

ANYWAY! Thank You so much!

Comment: Just move the tooltip generation to inside the loop http://jsfiddle.net/u1L726hw/. You could also switch to Tooltip instead of MultiTooltip

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You even can't imagine how much buthurt made this chart to me :)
Good luck! Thanx one more time!

Comment: No worries. It's been fun figuring this one out!